# Most idiomatic implementation of `[a -> a] -> (a -> a)`

Tags: function, haskell, function-composition

If I have a list of functions, each of the type `a -> a` for some type, what is the most shortest, elegant and idiomatic way to combine them; preferably without adding extra dependencies?

Some variants include

```
foo (x:xs) = x . (foo xs)
foo [] = id
```

and

```
foo = foldr (.) id
```

and

```
foo = appEndo . mconcat . map Endo
```

but for some reason I’m expecting to find something nicer.

Comment: `foldr (.) id` no?

Comment: What do you want differently from the `foldr` version? It's 12 characters so not exactly long, clear, and has no dependencies and abstracts all the details of recursion.

Comment: It is already pretty good, but I always have to sit and think for a little while, and was looking for something more memorable. But feel free to put “`foldr (.) id is the best you can get” as an answer :-)

Comment: `foldr1 (.)` - for nonempty lists

Comment: `mconcat . map = foldMap`, so `foo = appEndo . foldMap Endo`, which might be slightly nicer.  (That's [`Data.Foldable.foldMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap).)

Comment: With [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html#v:ala) or [`newtype`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-0.2/docs/Control-Newtype.html#v:ala) you can write `ala Endo foldMap`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd say you're not going to beat

```
comp = foldr (.) id
```

Why? Well we have a list of things and we're trying to reduce it in a right associative way.

If you look at the implementations of `and`, `sum`, `maximum` and similar, you'll see that this is how they're implemented in the standard library, I don't think you get more idiomatic than that :)

Tangent: I hesitate to add the `foldr1` variant mentioned in comments because I'd say that it's unexpected behavior for this to be partial, unlike say `maximum` where it clearly must be.

Comment: If I look at the implementations of `and`, `sum`, `maximum` and similar, I wonder why there is no name for `foldr (.) id` then ;-)

Comment: @JoachimBreitner That's not a bad question :) Unfortunately I have no answer other than "Probably random chance"

Answer (score 6):

Another one, which may not be shorter than `foldr (.) id` but which I think is cute:

```
foo = flip (foldr id)
```

Comment: For people that this confused at first (like me), using `id` as a function of type `a -> b -> b` reifies the type `a` with the type `b -> b`. So foldr id (foldr's type is (`a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`), has type `b -> [b -> b] -> b`, and so `flip (foldr id)` has type `[c -> c] -> c -> c` which is the same as `[c -> c] -> (c -> c)`

Comment: For more clarification, this use of `id` is often known as `($)`. `($)` is just `id` with a more specific type (`(a -> b) -> a -> b` instead of `a -> a`). I believe he used `id` here because it is shorter. When written out, this solution can be written as `foo l x = foldr ($) x l`. This allows you to see what is going on, i.e. `foo l x = l1 $ l2 $ l3 $ l4 $ .. ln $ x`, which of course is the same as `(l1 . l2 . l3 . l4 . .. ln) x` which is jozefg's solution.