# about haskell higher order function

Tags: haskell

I'm asked to write a function "pipeline" which has type `[a -> a] -> [a] -> [a]`, in such a pipeline, each function in the original function list is applied in turn to each element of the input. Eg, pipeline `[(+1),(*2),pred]` `[1,2,3]` would return `[1,3,5]`.

The answer from the solution sheet is `pipeline = map . foldr (.) id`, which I don't quite understand. How can this solution come up?

Comment: I suggest you look up the definitions of `map` (.) `foldr` and `id` and evaluate a small example by hand. This will enlighten you! It should be enough to see what `foldr (.) id [(+1), (*2)]` evaluates to.

Comment: Check out this answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777555/most-idiomatic-implementation-of-a-a-a-a/19778147#19778147

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about `foldr` is that

```
foldr f z xs
```

replaces every (:) in `xs` with `f` and the empty list with `z`

Note that

```
[(+1), (*2)]
```

is shorthand for

```
(+1) : (*2) : []
```

You should now be ables to see what

```
foldr (.) id   ((+1) : (*2) : [])
```

evaluates to. And from this, you will be able to understand the whole expression.

Answer (score 1):

Folds somehow are quite confusing, though they're actually very simple. Especially the right fold: it basically does nothing else but replace each `:` in a list with some alternative given function, and the list's `nil` with the init value. For your example:

```
foldr (.) id [(+1),(*2),pred]
≡ foldr (.) id ( (+1) : (*2) : pred : [] )
≡                (+1) . (*2) . pred . id
```

so this simply chains all the functions in a list to a big composition.

Once you've got this chain, applying it to all values in another list is trivial, an obvious job for `map`.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem is having a function of type : `[a -> a] -> (a -> a)` i.e convert a list of functions to a one function.

`foldr` has type: `(b -> c -> c) -> c -> [b] -> c`

Lets see how the type fits:

- `(b -> c -> c) -> c -> [b] -> c`
- Replace `b` with `(a -> a)` : `((a -> a) -> c -> c) -> c -> [a -> a] -> c`
- Replace `c` with `(a -> a)` : `((a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> (a -> a) -> [a -> a] -> (a -> a)`
- Type of function `(.)` is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, which is what we have in first type in the previous signature, (ours were all `a`), so we can use `(.)` there.
- For second part i.e `(a -> a)` we can use `id` function.
- Lets fit these: `(.) id` and we are left with `[a -> a] -> (a -> a)` part, which is what we needed
- So, `foldr (.) id` gives us `[a -> a] -> (a -> a)`

After that the `map` part is just applying the resulting function of the `foldr` to each element of list.

NOTE: Use a whiteboard to understand all this till your subconscious get used to do this ;)